# How is Ethanol categorized in the 12 BImSchV (Germans implementation of Seveso Directive)

Tags: germany, environmental

The 12 BImSchV (essentially germany implementation of the Seveso III directive, as far as I understand) defines certain industrial or other plants as hazardous, according to the substances stored there. [This attachment lists the substances and substance categories](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bimschv_12_2000/anhang_i.html). Ethanol (alcohol) is absent, even when using many alternative names. What is the appropriate category for alcohol?

The most likely categories are flammable liquids, 1.2.5.1 to 1.2.5.3 (the tresholds are vastly different!), however I can't tell which specific one. Categories 1.1 (toxic fluids) are also, or additionally, possible. What is it?

Update upon further search:

- it *appears* the entries in the table linked above reference [EU 1272/2008, Annex VI](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32008R1272&from=de#d1e43-325-1) where ethanol is listed as "Flam. liq. 2" (along "acute tox. 3), so ethanol would be an "entzündbare Flüssigkeiten der Kategorie 2" - correct?
- EU 1272/2008 has been changed by, so far at least, 17 ATP, these usually change, add or remove some of the entries in the annexes. Is there a collated version of the annexes aof EU 1272/2008 taking into account all ATP? Is there a quick way to find all ATP referring to EU 1272/2008?

Comment: Alcohol is not a plant product but a product of fermentation, and thus is a *bacteria* product!

Comment: @Trish I think mart’s referring to ethanol, C₂H₆O, a substance that’s classified as _an_ [alcohol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol%5F%28chemistry%29) (chemically speaking). I’d think _the limiting factor_ might be _other_ compounds appearing in your chemical reaction, but I _really don’t know_. It’s not like you’re simply having ethanol and doing nothing else with it.

Comment: @Trish this is plant as in manufacturing plant, not as in flora.

Comment: @mart: have a look at https://gestis.dguv.de/data?name=010420 - does that answer your question?

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX yes! provided the info is up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Institute for Occupational Safety and Health of the German Social Accident Insurance](https://www.dguv.de/ifa/) maintains a substance data base, [GESTIS](https://gestis.dguv.de/), which lists safety and regulation related data for chemical substances.

While they have a limited liability statement, this is a very official ressource used for all kinds occupational safety questions.
(The individual substance "sheets" do not give a "last updated on" date, but I just checked and the web site indicates the last update to the data base was today.)

[Link to **ethanol** section "Regulation"](https://gestis.dguv.de/data?name=010420&lang=en#1100)